# Torque due to the change in linear momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

In the problem I've been trying to solve, a mass on a massless rope is let out of the edge of a rotating cylindrical spaceship, thus increasing its moment of inertia. However, the system slows down as the mass is let out, so there must be a torque on the cylinder.

I can't really understand how it arises -- is it due to gravity? But it's a spaceship, and gravity in space is minimal. Is it due to tension in the rope? Then can we use the centripetal force equation (F=m) to find the torque on the system if we know the length of the rope?

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Is the mass directed radially out with an impulse, or is it just detached from the spaceship. And what is the role of the rope if it is loose and does not hold any tension. How is the problem different from firing a gun from a spaceship?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the axis in which you are calculating torque. As the force here is the centrifugal(or centripetal), the torque about the axis of rotation will be 0. Hint to solve the problem: What remains constant in a system when net torque in 0.

Comment: Linear momentum is constant, right? And I'm looking for the torque about the axis of rotation -- I understand why it must be zero. So the torque must be internal, between the mass and the spaceship?

Comment: It's angular momentum. Linear momentum is conserved if force is 0. Yes, the torque is internal.

Comment: So I have to calculate the torque on the cylinder and the mass and they should be of the same magnitude, but in opposite directions?

Comment: You can just use the axis of rotation as your axis for calculating torque. As $r_\perp$ is $0$ in that case, both the torque will just be 0.

Comment: Okay, but how can I explain that the angular speed is changing?

Comment: Just use the formula for angular momentum conservation. $I_1w_1 = I_2w_2$

Comment: The question is asking to show how the torque arises on a diagram :( will it be enough to show that it's perpendicular to the axis of rotation and hence is zero due to the conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: Have you been taught about Coriolis force?

Comment: No, I've never heard of it

Comment: It should be fine then. If you want to know the force that will speed up the mass and slow down the cylinder, it is, in reality, the Coriolis force.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks so much